# Anaconda environments: Is the base environment just a waste of space?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a questions about the way packages are managed by conda.

If I install anaconda, it will come with a lot of scientific packages, such as `numpy`. All in all, Anaconda uses quite some disk space.

However, the recommended way of using Anaconda is to create environments. So, I go,

```
conda create -my_env python
```

This creates a new environment. This does not have `numpy` etc.  I can install `numpy` and all other packages.  But does that mean I have `numpy` twice? Once in `base` and once in `my_env`? Also, since I am not using `base` is that just wasted space?

The baseline is that I'd like to understand whether the `base` environment is just a waste of space if we're not supposed to us it.

Comment: You can certainly use the base environment! What's not suggested (I think) is to install a lot of other/new packages into the base environment. Conda tries to be smart about managing space, and doesn't create new copies of every file when you create a new environment, it creates a tiny file that points to the original location, and every environment points to that same place so not much extra space is used. If you don't want the `base` environment to take up so much space, you can use [Miniconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html)